# CodeIgniter display array in controller after retrieving data from model

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Why am I getting an empty array when I try to `print_r` or `var_dump` an array (which is the data from the model)

```
$section = $this->input->post('section');
$students = $this->SectionsModel->getSectionMembers($section);
var_dump($students);
```

And the model:

```
function getSectionMembers($section_id){
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM students WHERE SECTION_ID = "'.$section_id.'" ORDER BY LNAME ASC');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

And the output returns `array(0) { }`

Can I print the array in the controller immediately? I am doing this to test something.

Comment: Try using var_dump($students)

Comment: Yes that's it, I just mistyped. My bad. But it still doesn't work even if it's `var_dump($students)`

Comment: If you're getting an empty array, that's likely as simple as the query returning no results. Have you validated that it does?

Comment: Yes, I tried to display it in a view and it does display data

Answer (score 0):

You missed something from `section_id` and `section` variables. It is searching for a parameter called $section_id inside your model.
Try to change those.

```
$students = $this->SectionsModel->getSectionMembers($section_id);
var_dump($students);
```

Comment: I have something in there, I just didn't include it in my question because it's a common sense. `$section = $this->input->post('section');`

Comment: try to dump first the section if it contains data. `var_dump($section); exit();`

Comment: maybe something is not right in your model. try var_dump inside your model `getSectionMembers`

Answer (score 0):

try to var_dump ($this->db->last_query()) and figure out the problem